# Understanding the basics of php

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I have moved onto now learning php and have already a question to ask. I have successfully enabled my script to connect to a database I am toying around with (Ignore any security flaws) I am just learning. But I am able to connect and show my table information IF the script is all in one file. I then tried to create a separate connection file and include it into my file which shows the table data but it just shows nothing but it isn't failing to connect?

So here is my index.php

```
<?php require 'db_connect.php'; ?>

<?php

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Users");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['email'] . " " . $row['display_name'] . " " . $row['user_id'];
  echo "<br>";
}


?>
```

And my connection file:

```
<?php

//Connect

$con = mysqli_connect('#####','#####','#####','#####');

// Check connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo 'failed to connect ' . mysqli_connect_error();
}



mysqli_close($con);


?>
```

If I have just the one file it shows the info - If I separate it fails? Any pointers?

Comment: You close the connection within the connection file, so what do you expect? A zombie connection or what?

Comment: takeout `mysqli_close($con);`  from the connection file.

Comment: hehe I'm loving this... I have been through such situations when I was learning... don't worry,  just do what is said by other folks. You can keep experimenting while learning. and yes,  remove `mysqli_close($con);`

Comment: It makes sense to me now! Duh yep thats me the ultimate newb!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're closing the connection you just made in your connection file before executing the query...

put the following line to the end of your index.php to close the connection ***after*** your query:

```
mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well youre closing the connection at the end of the connection file, so the connection is not availible if you include it.

Remove that from your connection file

```
mysqli_close($con);
```

and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the close connection statement , you should remove it.
remove this part :
           mysqli_close($con);

you can also put that into a function and call that function an a close connection file.the same goes for the connecting you could put the connection in a separate file and even just add a include statement like:
       include 'connection.php';
hope that makes sense